# Quantum computers as verifiable random number generators

Tags: random-number-generators

This article (which has been out since 2016) describes the use of (at least 2) quantum computers to generate random number sequences with guaranteed entropy level above a starting level: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0489.pdf

The question I have is: has any quantum computing platform vendor successfully implemented this protocol?

Comment: You probably want to go back a bit further in time for original references to the concept. For example, https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys2300

Comment: I haven't kept up to date with these things (hence the comment) however, I assume a fundamental feature of all schemes is that you have to share entanglement between the two quantum computers. I'm not aware of any platforms that can do this at the moment.

Comment: If you don't care about the devices being quantum computers then yes, randomness expansion protocols have successfully been implemented. See [Device-independent randomness expansion against quantum side information](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-020-01147-2) and [Device-independent randomness expansion with entangled photons](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-020-01153-4).

Answer (score 1):

No one has done this yet. The closest is probably ["Loophole-free Bell inequality violation with superconducting circuits"](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-023-05885-0) from 2023.

Violating a Bell inequality is a prerequisite for certifying randomness. As is doing the violation with something you could build a quantum computer out of (like superconducting qubits). So this experiment demonstrates some of the necessary pieces in the necessary context.